# Text and table view data storage in swift

Tags: swift

Could anyone tell me what the way of storing a long text in a swift app is. Let's suppose I have an app that has a table view and when I chose a row I go to a new scene where I have a big page filled by text.

The question is where do I have to store the data of the table's row and the whole text? And how?

Do I have to make a model? Is it just one for both the table and the text? Or more than one. Is there any tutorial that explains this exact situation or close to it?

Comment: I want a local data file so that the user gets the information without a connection to the internet.

Comment: just updated my answer with some idea on this. please take some time researching on it to get a full understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Parse.com](https://parse.com/) framework to retrieve data from a database. There is a lot of [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide) on this.

In [this link](http://blog.bizzi-body.com/2015/02/05/ios-swift-parse-com-part-2-table-view/) you can find a tutorial that will explain you how to load data from Parse and show it in your UITableView.

**Storing Local (in-memory store):**

For storing without a internet connection you could use Core Data Stack with NSInMemoryStoreType as storeType. [This tutorial](https://realm.io/news/jesse-squires-core-data-swift/) will give you a nice idea on how it works.

You can declare a model like it follows:

```
struct CoreDataModel {
  let name: String
  let bundle: NSBundle
  init(name: String, bundle: NSBundle)
  // other properties & methods
}
```

And then manage it with:

```
let model = CoreDataModel(name: "MyModel", bundle: myBundle)
let stack = CoreDataStack(model: model,
                      storeType: NSInMemoryStoreType,
                concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)

// Use context
stack.managedObjectContext
```